# Trying to display post based on two variables

Tags: conditional, variable

I am setting three variables like so ...

```
{% set featureEntryIds = craft.entries({ section: 'blog', featurePost: 1, limit: 1 }).ids() %}

{% set articleClass = entry.id in featureEntryIds ? 'featured' %}`

{% set featuredPostLayout = entry.featuredPostLayout == 'subtleBar' or 'largeFeature' %}
```

Then I am trying to use a conditional to display posts where the `featurePost` lightswitch field is true

AND

`featuredPostLayout` radio field is either `subtleBar` or `largeFeature`

```
{% if articleClass and featuredPostLayout %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: There are a couple of obvious problems with your example code. First off, you're limiting the featured IDs query to one entry. I assume that's a mistake, as you're checking if an entry ID is "in" your list of featured IDs. Secondly, you're using a ternary conditional, without the "false" clause.